# Entity Framework eager loads associated collection but won't lazy load it

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I've tried to get the `Studies` property of the `Department` object to lazy load, but it will only load when I eagerly load it. I've added a `DepartmentId` to the `Study` class with no results, used `ICollection`, `ISet` and `virtual`. Public and private setters seems to make no difference (and it shouldn't). Nothing seems to work. Using EF 6.1.

```
public class Department
{
  private Department() {}

  public Department(DepartmentTitle title)
  {
    if (title == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

    this.Title = title;
    this.Studies = new HashSet<Study>();
  }

  public int DepartmentId { get; private set; }

  public virtual DepartmentTitle Title { get; private set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Study> Studies { get; set; }
}

public class Study
{
  private Study() {}

  public Study(StudyTitle title, Department department)
  {
    if (title == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if (department == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

    this.Title = title;
    this.Department = department;
  }

  public int StudyId { get; private set; }

  public virtual StudyTitle Title { get; private set; }
  public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

// Here I save the department and study objects
// I verified they exist in the database    
var department = new Department(new DepartmentTitle("Department Title Here"));
department.Studies.Add(new Study(new StudyTitle("Study Title Here"), department));
data.SaveChanges();

// In a new database context
// Here I try to lazy load the Studies property, but get null
// It works if I add Include("Studies") before Where()
Department department = data.Departments.Where(d => d.Title.Value == "Department Title Here").Single();
System.Console.WriteLine(department.Studies.First().Title.Value);

// DepartmentTitle and StudyTitle are simple complex types with a Value property
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Study class needs a public or protected parameterless constructor to work with lazy loading: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx)

Comment: That's weird, but it works. I assumed it made no difference since it says everywhere how EF can "just" use reflection to access whatever it needs. Apparently not.

Comment: I wish I had stumbled across this a couple weeks ago. Been banging my head trying to figure out why lazy loading wouldn't work with my entities. I had a private parameterless constructor on my entity which worked fine with EF for loading the entity from the database. Changed it to protected, and lazy loading finally works. Aargh!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually load Studies:

```
department.Studies.Load();
System.Console.WriteLine(department.Studies.First().Title.Value);
```

Otherwise they won't exist and `First()` will crash.

So either you `Include()` your entity for eager loading, or you `Load()` it later in a lazy way.

Comment: +1. I was sure this approach would work, but it didn't. It lead me in the right direction, however, or it will lead someone else in that direction.