# Strange behaviour of Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am using ASP.NET 5 and Entity Framework 7 and faced with a strange behaviour.

Problem overview: I've got some models:

- Section
- Category
- Procedure
- Sections *contains* Category
- Category *contains* Procedure

When I am trying to access `Categories` in `Sections` it's all OK:

```
var section = repository.Sections.First(x => x.ID == sectionId);
model.Name = section.Name;
model.Categories = section.Categories;
```

But when I am trying to access `Procedures` in `Category` I get an empty list:

```
var category = repository.Categories.First(x => x.ID == categoryId);
model.Name = category.Name;
model.Procedures = category.Procedures;
```

And the strange part: when I add this line after previous code it all works fine:

```
var tmp = repository.Procedures.Where(x => x.CategoryId == category.ID).ToList();
```

I am using SQL Server 2014 Express

Why does this happen?

My models:

(*Note:* the `ID` field is defined in the `AbstractModel`)

**Section**

```
[Table("sections")]
public class Section:AbstractModel
{
    // ... some unimportant fields

    // Relations
    public ICollection<Category> categories;
    public ICollection<PriceCategory> priceCategories;

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories
    {
        get { return this.categories ?? (this.categories = new List<Category>()); }
        set { categories = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<PriceCategory> PriceCategories
    {
        get { return this.priceCategories ?? (this.priceCategories = new List<PriceCategory>()); }
        set { priceCategories = value; }
    }
}
```

**Category**

```
[Table("categories")]
public class Category : AbstractCategory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Relation with section
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
    public int SectionID { get; set; }

    // Relation with procedures
    private ICollection<Procedure> procedures;

    public virtual ICollection<Procedure> Procedures
    {
        get { return this.procedures ?? (this.procedures = new List<Procedure>()); }
        set { procedures = value; }
    }
}
```

**Procedure**

```
[Table("procedures")]
public class Procedure : AbstractProcedure
{
    // Relation with cateogry
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID   { get; set; }
}
```

I think the problem in the lazy loading, but I have no idea, how to fix it.
It's very strange - why `Category` loads just fine, but `Procedure` doesn't?

They've got very same code.

What the way to solve this problem?

Comment: did you tried to do things like that : model.Procedures = category.Procedures.ToList(); ?

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331244/entity-framework-eager-loads-associated-collection-but-wont-lazy-load-it

Comment: EF7 does not support lazy loading. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797

Comment: Thanks. I  think the solution can be something like: 
`var category = repository.Categories.Include(p => p.Procedures).First(p => p.ID == categoryId);`, but `Include` is undefined (very strange).

*Or just don't use EF7 yet...*